# Realm Crash when writing a double in swift after upgrade to latest realm version 5.0

Tags: realm, swift5

I have been using Realm db in my iOS app for past 2 years without any issues. After the recent upgrade to Realm cocoa 5.0 - it crashed with the following error when trying to write a double to Realm within a write transaction.

```
class QtUsage: Object {
   @objc dynamic var usageCount = 1.0
}
/// In some code flow - we have the following - this code has been in use for several months now. 
try realm.write {
    self.usageCount += self.perUsageCount
}
```

I have attached the screenshot below. Is this a known issue?

It also occurred in one more place

```
/Users/realm/workspace/realm_realm-core_release_6.0.4/src/realm/array.hpp:1136: [realm-core-6.0.4] Assertion failed: has_refs()
0   Realm                               0x000000010d4baf7c _ZN5realm4utilL18terminate_internalERNSt3__118basic_stringstreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEE + 28
1   Realm                               0x000000010d4bb236 _ZN5realm4util9terminateEPKcS2_lOSt16initializer_listINS0_9PrintableEE + 390
2   Realm                               0x000000010d3a0daa _ZNK5realm16ClusterNodeInner7try_getENS_6ObjKeyERNS_11ClusterNode5StateE + 826
3   Realm                               0x000000010d3ac829 _ZNK5realm11ClusterTree8is_validENS_6ObjKeyE + 41
4   Realm                               0x000000010d42863b _ZNK5realm8ConstObj8is_validEv + 59
5   Realm                               0x000000010d159df3 ___ZN12_GLOBAL__N_110makeGetterIddEEP11objc_objectm_block_invoke + 35
```

Thanks

[image: 5.0]

Comment: Filed a bug report to Realm github as well - https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/6532

Comment: We are using 5.0 and our project heavily relies on writing Doubles and it's working correctly. Can you provide a better code snippet so we can see more complete code? I realize it was working before but it's too short to how its implemented. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sure let me work on isolating the code

Comment: Thanks @Jay - As part of isolating the code - i did see this is happening when the writes are in background thread - incidentally those writes were doubles - but problem is not related to Double as i thought. Thanks for your pointers

Comment: The issue is going away if I call realm.refresh() before the writes in the background thread. Somehow the exact same issue is NOT happening in 4.4.1 but consistently happens in 5.0

Comment: Hmm. That could be how the threading is set up - probably would need to see that code. However.... We are having issues with 5.0 as well not returning correct data with filters so I am dubious that 5.0 is stable at all.